# how to sort xml?

Tags: xml

i have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<root>
  <data name="UserName">User Name</data>
  <data name="Password">Password</data>
  <data name="LogIn">Log In</data>
  <data name="InvalidPassword">Invalid password</data>
  <data name="InvalidUserName">Invalid username</data>
</root>
```

how do i sort the file itself?
i want to sort by 'name'.

Comment: Is it parsed into some kind of DOM-like api at all?

Comment: XML is nothing more than a common structure for a text file. There are no commands, and it isn't meant to be read by humans. Any sorting will be done with whatever program you have using the XML file. Need more info to handle that part of it...

Comment: `XML` is a way of representing the data - sorting comes into play when you display the data. What's your usecase?

Comment: I do not know about "aplhabetical sorting" functions. Why do you want to sort a XML file, if you do not have to?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an XSLT template that would do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="root/data">
          <xsl:sort select="@name" order="ascending"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
     </root>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="data">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I try yours but have no succeess. Can you post your sample input & output?

Comment: I've used the input of the question (with a proper xml header), and the exact XSLT template I provided in the answer. The result is: <?xml version="1.0"?><root><data name="InvalidPassword">Invalid password</data><data name="InvalidUserName">Invalid username</data><data name="LogIn">Log In</data><data name="Password">Password</data><data name="UserName">User Name</data></root>